# How to draw circle using 'xypic ' package?

Tags: diagrams, xy-pic

I have little knowledge about the package `xypic`.

I am stuck with the following problems:

1. I cannot  able drow a circle with radius BC, centered at C.
2. I want to draw the five dots on the line.
3. For better looking I want to draw the points 2, 1, 0, -1 and -2 as well as A, B, C, D and E out side the line.

Here is my effort:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xypic}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix{
\ar[dddddd] \\
.2 & & & & &\\
.1 & & &D & & \\
.0 \ar[r]^p & \ar[rrrr] &A  & C &B &\\
.-1& & &E \\
.-2 & & &\ar[uuuu]\\
\ar[uuuuuu]
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you post a picture of how the output should look like? I have the feeling that this is less a commutative diagram and more a general diagram that can also been drawn using PSTricks or TikZ (or …).

Comment: Actually i don't know how to post picture.Please tell me the way.  Then I shall try to post picture.

Answer (score 1):

With PSTricks.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-2.25,-1.25)(2.25,1.25)
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle=-135]
        (-2,0){E}
        (-1,0){D}
        (0,0){C}
        (1,0){B}
        (2,0){A}
    \pstLineAB{E}{A}
    \pstCircleOA{C}{B}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I want to do this using the package I said.

Comment: When I compile this shows an error :  ./myfile.text:2:File'standalone.cls' not found . \usepackage. I dont know what is .cls.Please tell me.

Comment: I an using 'kile 2.1 beta 4'.My system-ubuntu 10.04 is up to date.What to do me now ?

Comment: @MdKutubuddinSardar TeXLive distribution with Ubuntu 10.04 is very old(may be 2009).[Installing Vanilla TeXlive gives all latest packages](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/15717), but don't do it if you are unaware of linux installation. for the time being change the `\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}` to `\documentclass{article} \usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}` run with `pdflatex` engine